# Defined Names in an If then statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to define Branches by State, example would be branches 1,2,3 are in Minnesota and branches 4,5,6 are in Iowa. So, I defined them to the corresponding state to use for my IF statement. However, when I put the defined group into my formula nothing comes back unless that C column is blank. Is there a way to make these groups work or should I try to think of different way to get my state per branch.

```
=IF(C4=Minnesota_BRs,"MINNESOTA","")
```

Comment: I have used the formula below and it works for that one state but if I want it to test between multiple state such as Colorado? Not sure if I need to keep the ISERROR function in there or if that second nested if just doesn't work because I have branch in colorado 9 rows down and it just gives me an error. Please Help! 
 
 =IF((VLOOKUP(C4,Minnesota,1,FALSE)),"Minnesota",IF(VLOOKUP(C4,Colorado,1,TRUE),"COLORADO",""))

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the `IF function` to check if a value is part of a range.

Try the following formula:

The `VLOOKUP` will check if `C4` is part of `Minnesota_BRs`. If that's the case, `ISERROR` will evaluate to `FALSE` (and the `IF` formula will result in `MINNESOTA`).

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C4,Minnesota_BRs,1;FALSE)),"","MINNESOTA")
```

**EDIT** in regards to the comment under the question:

If you want to **check several ranges** you can - as you suggest build a nested-IF formula. I think you are close, just the order is not correct. Use the following:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C4,Minnesota,1,FALSE)),IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C4,Iowa,1,FALSE)),"","Iowa"),"Minnesota")
```

However, I think for your case, where you probably want to check the branches in many states, this is really efficient. You will get a terrible formula.

You might rather set up a table with all branches and states, and the **use a formula that finds the value inside this multi column table, gives you the column number and then picks the state from the table header:**

[image: Find column that contains a value in Excel]

```
={INDEX(E4:G4,,MIN(IF(E5:G7=C4,COLUMN(A1:C1))))}
```

(Be aware that this is an array formula, type it in and leave the cell with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`)

The formula is not easy to understand. Just that much information:

The `E5:G7=C4` part inside the array function will check all values in the table and form an array that looks like this:

[image: Array with <code>TRUE</code> and <code>FALSE</code> in Excel]

As you see, `5` results to TRUE. The `IF` function will then pick the column number (which is `2` here). The `INDEX` function then picks the second state name - Iowa.

I hope that is somewhat useful for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try!

Comment: If you have time could you please look at my comment to my first question because your answers work perfect for the one state but what if I want it to look at the branch number then pull a different state

Comment: @BrotenTogstad I have now updated my answer and maybe have an alternative suggestion for you.